# TeamCity NTLM groups

Tags: windows, continuous-integration, teamcity, ntlm

I am evaluating TeamCity on Windows, using NTLM authentication.

It seems TeamCity allows any valid user in the domain. This is undesirable.

How can I restrict the users when using NTLM in TeamCity to a specific group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Authentication+Modules):

"All NT domain users that can log on to the machine running the TeamCity server, can also log in to TeamCity using the same credentials. i.e. to log in to TeamCity users should provide domain and user name (DOMAIN\username) and their domain password."

Please note that users will be granted only minimum permissions to the system (same permissions of the guest user).

Comment: My question was how to restrict it; I know it allows access to anyone, because that's exactly the problem I am having.

Comment: you have to edit <TeamCity data directory>/config/auth-config.xml: set "allowCreatingNewUsersByLogin" property to false. [Here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+Authentication+Settings) you can find more details.